# Why doesn't NSString getCharacters work in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
-(void)myFunction {

        unichar myBuffer[5];
        NSRange range = {0, 3};
        NSString *string = [NSString alloc];
        string = @"123";
        [string getCharacters:myBuffer :range];
}
```

Gets warning

> ! NSString may not respond
>   to '-getCharacters::'

then does a SIGABRT when I run it.
Why????? Or better yet how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 5):

To use `getCharacters:range:`, write this line of code:

```
[string getCharacters:myBuffer range:range];
```

In Objective-C, method names are split up by arguments (a feature that derives from its Smalltalk heritage).  So your original code was trying to send a message that's essentially named `getCharacters: :`, which isn't found.  The corrected version sends the message `getCharacters: range:`.

The `getCharacters:myBuffer` construct says that the first argument to `getCharacters:range:` is `myBuffer`.  Similarly, the `range:range` construct says the second argument is your `NSRange` named `range`.

Comment: Ummmm, if I knew enough to understand your answer then I would have already known enough not to have to ask the question.  Alternately put, I'm a novice.  Can you write me a sample line of code.  I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: The line of code at the beginning of the answer should work for you.  Replace your `[string getCharacters:myBuffer :range];` line with it and it should work.