# In iOS, printing nil memory address to display 0x0 means no storage space?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know the difference between `nil` and `[NSNull null]`, so I use `NSLog(@"nil==== =%p",nil), and NSLog(@"null====%p",[NSNull null])` to print out their memory addresses, but the result of printing is `nil==== =0x0, null=== 0x1022c2f08`, I don't quite understand what `0x0` means, can anyone help me understand?

Comment: `0x0` is hexadecimal syntax for the decimal value `0`

Comment: Does it take up memory space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone - \[NSNull getCharacters:\]:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663988/iphone-nsnull-getcharacters)

Comment: That depends.  It is a keyword in objective C, which has the same type as a pointer.  If you store a `nil` value somewhere then sure, it takes up storage.  If you use it in your program, technically that occupies storage in the program segment of memory.  But by your apparent understanding of memory, I'm inclined to say the answer is "no".  It's certainly not an object that can be instanced, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Setting a pointer to nil (nothing, 0, null).. means the pointer points to nothing or the address 0x0 aka.. 0..  However.. `[NSNull null]` is an OBJECT that is used to represent nil/null in a dictionary because the dictionary in iOS cannot store "nil" values.. IE: When parsing JSON, iOS stores "NSNull" to represent nil in a dictionary. Think of "NSNull" as the boxed version of the primitive "nil".. `"NSNull - A singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects that don’t allow nil values." - Apple`

Comment: @paddy Yeah, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Brandon I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### nil

Literal null value for Objective-C objects。it means an Objective-C object pointer that points to 0x0。all objective c pointers start with nil.

### NSNull

A singleton object used to represent null object。It is wrapper for null object, so that you can put it in a collection like NSArray/NSDictionary

```
NSArray * a1 = @[[NSNull null]]; //Good
NSArray * a2 = @[nil]; // Crash
```

[More Details](https://nshipster.com/nil/)

Comment: Well, the link content is very detailed, and it makes me understand now, thank you.